# Chrome: How to close tab from within a page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to close Chrome Tab from within a html page?
What i search for is some javascript that will will say: Click here to close tab!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use the window.close() function, just like you would when closing a popup window or a regular window:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml

**Update:** This no longer seems to work on newer versions of Chrome. However, opening a new window with:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('foo.html', '_self', '');">Open window</a>
```

and using

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">Close window</a>
```

in `foo.html` works for me in Chrome 17. See also http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23c03746e3aa03f9&hl=en.